# SQLite, insert data into a DB from different Views

Tags: ios, database, xcode, sqlite, insert

**We have declared the following code in the default ViewController.m:**

```
-(void)saveData{
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                           name.text, address.text, phone.text];
    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        name.text = @"";
        address.text = @"";
        phone.text = @"";
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
}
```

}

-(void)findContact{

```
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT address, phone FROM contacts WHERE name=\"%@\"", name.text];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            address.text = addressField;
            NSString *phoneField = [[NSString alloc]
                                    initWithUTF8String:(const char *)
                                    sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            phone.text = phoneField;

            status.text = @"Match found";
        } else {
            status.text = @"Match not found";
            address.text = @"";
            phone.text = @"";

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
```

}

-(void)viewDidLoad{

```
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
dirPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir=[dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"]];
NSFileManager *filemgr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
if([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]==NO)
{
    const char *dbpath=[databasePath UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)";

        if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            status.text = @"Failed to create table";
        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    } else {
        status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
    }
}
```

}

**It works, but we want to access to that database (contactDB) from different viewControllerName.m ; we have tried the following:**

//  Scene2ViewController.m

-(void)incrementoBarra {

if (barra.progress == 1) {

```
   //In this method we want to insert the address data into the specified name. 

   sqlite3_stmt *statement;
   const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

   if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
       NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                              @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%d\")",
                              usuario, tiempo];
       const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
       sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
       if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
       {
           sqlite3_finalize(statement);
           sqlite3_close(contactDB);
       }
   }

   //


   [self performSelector:@selector(hideImage) withObject: nil afterDelay:1.0];


}
```

}

**It didn´t work due to errors with the variables and the database as these were not well declared**

***How do we have to implement those variables and database to work with them from different .m?
Thank you for your time!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to this question there are allot of answers, so i'll just explain the one i would be going for, and try to explain why. Here goes!

Since you've got similar logic that you want to use in different locations (in this case multiple files), i would move this logic to a new class (.h and .m file for implementation). Considering it's logic that interacts with the database i would go ahead and name it "DatabaseManager". This class should now give you access to the logic you'd need.

To make sure you're always able to acces DatabaseManager, it might be smart to make it a Singleton (see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that the logic is not so similar. I´ve two classname.m -s in the project and in each one I´ve to insert a different value in the database (in one the address and in the other the phone),depending on the identificator(in my case is the name).The thing is that I dont know if just to insert a value(address or phone) with a especified name into the database, I can use an easier way to do that. I would really appreciate any help, as I am stuck in this proyect.

Comment: Even though the logic seems to differ, there is definitely some similarities. Opening and closing the database for example. This can then easily be combined into specific functions within the manager. These functions can then be used for your more specific ones, such as inserting contacts or retrieving addresses. That would allow for the view controllers to call the addContact or the getAllAddresses function.

Comment: Ok, I will try that lets see what I get

Comment: //  DatabaseManager.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"

@interface DatabaseManager : UIViewController
{
    ...
    NSString *databasePath;
    sqlite3 *contactDB;
}
... //I have declared *databasePath and *contactDB in DatabaseManager.m, now I want to use them in another viewController.m, how can I do that? even if I #import "DatabaseManager.h", I get the error of (undeclared values)